# Hidden time for angular-bootstrap-calendar

Tags: angularjs, angular-bootstrap

Here is a pretty clean and easy to use calendar made in Angularjs.

https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-bootstrap-calendar#documentation

For now, the events always have time, but I don't want to use it. How to hidden it?

Comment: the link is incorrect

Comment: sorry, I've updated link. thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can custom it via:

calendarConfig.templates.templateView

https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-bootstrap-calendar#configuring-the-calendar-default-config